# Why is this term $=1$

Tags: summation, exponentiation, closed-form

Can you tell me why

$$\frac{1}{r} \sum_{k=0}^{r-1} R_N(x^k) \sum_{s=0}^{r-1} e^{\frac{-2 \pi i s k}{r}}=1?$$

Here $R_N(x^k)$ is the remainder of $x^k$ Modulo $N$.

When I entered the last sum in Wolfram Alpha, it gave me $0$, so I am a Little bit confused here.

Thank you very much for your help.

(By the way: This Comes from the Shor-algorithm)

Comment: Since $\sum_{s=0}^{r-1} e^{\frac{-2 \pi i s k}{r}}=0$ as sum for geometric series shows,it does not vanish only when $k=0$. Thus we have $\frac{1}{r}R_N(1)\cdot r=1.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sum_{s=0}^{r-1} e^{\frac{-2 \pi i s k}{r}}$ equals $0$ unless $k=0$, in which case it equals $r$. So your expression is equal to
$$\frac{1}{r} R_N(x^0) r = R_N(1) = 1$$

Comment: thank you very much. This is what I wanted to see. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You face a geometric series. Thus $$S_k=\sum_{s=0}^{r-1} e^{\frac{-2 \pi i s k}{r}}=\frac{\left(1-e^{2 i \pi  k}\right) e^{\frac{2 i \pi  k}{r}-2 i \pi 
   k}}{1-e^{\frac{2 i \pi  k}{r}}}=e^{-\frac{i \pi  k (r-1)}{r}} \sin (\pi  k) \csc \left(\frac{\pi  k}{r}\right)$$ which is $0$ for all $k \neq 0$ and then the results already given in answers and comments.

Comment: All you need is $\sum_{s=0}^{r-1}\alpha^s = \dfrac{1-\alpha^r}{1-\alpha}$ if $\alpha \ne 1$. Here $\alpha = e^{\frac{-2\pi ik}{r}}$, so $1-\alpha^r = 0$.

Comment: For sure ! I just tried to clarify a bit using the OP initial concern. Cheers :-)